# Why does my nRF24L01 receive [13] when nothing is transmitted?

Tags: nrf24l01

I followed [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tB_GebqaGas) which is very similar to [this text tutorial](http://invent.module143.com/daskal_tutorial/raspberry-pi-3-wireless-pi-to-pi-python-communication-with-nrf24l01/) to configure a pair of nRF2L01 rf radios to communicate with each other, however when the ReceivePi.py is running it results in this repeatedly (and very fast), whether or not my second raspberry pi is transmitting:

```
Loaded payload reply of [1]
Received: [13]
Translating the receivedMessage into unicode characters

Loaded payload reply of [1]
Received: [13]
Translating the receivedMessage into unicode characters
```

Anyone have any advice on what might be going on?

I did notice that when the script first runs it gives me this:

```
Data Rate    = 1MBPS
Model        = nRF24L01
CRC Length   = Disabled
PA Power     = PA_MIN
```

While in the example it had `CRC Length = 16 bits`

I tried adding `radio.setCRCLength(NRF24.CRC_ENABLED)` to my receive python script, but it didn't have any effect. I also tried `radio.setCRCLength(NRF24.CRC_16)` and that had no effect either.

Is there some magic required to

Comment: I wasn't able to figure out how to make the radio work properly using the tutorial, however I was able to make the radio work using the library here: http://tmrh20.github.io/RF24/Linux.html

Comment: [This][1] answer fixed my issues

In lib_nrf24.py in function:

`def begin(self, csn_pin` ... after  `self.spidev.open` add:

    `self.spidev.max_speed_hz = 4000000`


  [1]: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/71730/possible-spi-issues-around-nrf24-operations-post-rpi-system-update

Answer (score 0):

To finish this question I will quote the solution the questioner *@nickvans* has given in a comment:

> I wasn't able to figure out how to make the radio work properly using the tutorial, however I was able to make the radio work using the library here: http://tmrh20.github.io/RF24/Linux.html