# Crash on radio.begin() (for NRF24 Module )

Tags: wireless, spi, nrf24l01

I have connected my NRF24 module as described at bottom of [this](http://tmrh20.github.io/RF24/RPi.html) webpage.

I cloned [that](https://github.com/nRF24/RF24) repository and have Build using SPIDEV (I have ensured SPI was enabled and double checked that SPI module works, following [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/spi/README.md) look back test at bottom of the webpage.

However when I build and launch `./gettingstarted`, is abruptly terminated.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/RF24/examples_linux $ ./gettingstarted
RF24/examples/GettingStarted/
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'
Aborted
```

I figured its from `radio.begin();`

Also if no NFR24 is connected to RPi , the same abort happens.

What I've missed , or doing wrong ?

<sub>***Using:***
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.4 (stretch)
Release:        9.4</sub>

Comment: The first link does not work. The 3rd is to a 6 year old obsolete tutorial.

Comment: @Milliways I updated the first link, and ensured the tutorial did the same loop back test as on official raspberry pi webpage. (I updated 3rd link as well). Do you think its issue with RPi itself ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the device interaction needs root access.

I got [help](https://github.com/nRF24/RF24/issues/440#issuecomment-396085327) from the github community, from the authors.

I have to use `sudo ./gettingstarted`

Comment: Definitely, `sudo` is required.