# NRF24 only works after reboot of Raspberry

Tags: nrf24l01

I used this tutorial to set up the NRF24 module:
http://invent.module143.com/daskal_tutorial/raspberry-pi-3-wireless-pi-to-arduino-communication-with-nrf24l01/

It works, but only the first time after a boot. So I have to reboot the raspberry and can run the program again. But only one time. Than I have to reboot again. Does anybody know the reason...? It took me hours to figure this out and only by chance I realized that the code works... :-D

Thank you for your answers.

Best Regards
Carsten

Comment: Could you put the relevant information in your question?  The link will eventually die.

Comment: Hi @Carsten, did you ever get this working? I'm also having strange issues.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/71730/possible-spi-issues-around-nrf24-operations-post-rpi-system-update) answer fixed my issues

In lib_nrf24.py in function:

`def begin(self, csn_pin` ... after  `self.spidev.open` add:

```
self.spidev.max_speed_hz = 4000000
```